# Doubt about the Gaussian state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-states

I am reading an article that makes an application using the Gaussian state. The author of the  article writes the Gaussian state as follows:
$$\psi(q) = [2\pi(\Delta q)^2]^{-\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\frac{q^2}{4(\Delta q)^2}}e^{i\frac{\tilde pq}{\hslash}}$$
and thereby we have the following relationships for your uncertainty

$$\langle Q\rangle = \tilde q$$
$$\langle P\rangle = \tilde p$$
$$\Delta Q = \sqrt{\langle Q^2 \rangle - \langle Q \rangle^2}=\Delta q$$
$$\Delta P= \sqrt{\langle P^2 \rangle - \langle P \rangle^2} = \frac{\hslash}{2\Delta q}$$

I was a little confused because, when I studied the Gaussian state by Cohen-Tannoudji's book *Quantum Mechanics*. Because in the complement C3 (Root mean square deviations of two conjugate observables) of his book, the expression of the Gaussian state is as follows:
$$\psi(q) = [2\pi(\Delta q)^2]^{-\frac{1}{4}}e^{-[\frac{q-\langle Q\rangle}{2(\Delta Q)}]^2}e^{i\frac{\langle P\rangle q}{\hslash}}$$

These two expressions for the Gaussian state are written a little differently from each other. I would like to know what is the difference between these two? And if there is any way to write the expression of the Gaussian state of Cohen-Tannoudji's book in the previous form of the article I was reading?

Comment: Can you provide us with the title of the article you were reading? I think they use different conventions.

Comment: thank you so much for trying to help me. The name of the article is "Quantifying continuous-variable realism" In section 3 of the article he makes the example for the Gaussian state and writes the expression that I showed.

Comment: So your first formula takes $\tilde{q}=0$. What of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Freire article, in Eq. (18), you define the "standard continuous-variable minimum-uncertainty Gaussian state" as
\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dq \psi(q-\bar{q})|q\rangle,\qquad\psi(q)=[2\pi(\Delta q)^2]^{-1/4} e^{-\frac{q^2}{4(\Delta q)^2}}e^{i\frac{\bar{p}q}{\hbar}}
\end{equation}
Just notice that the minimum-uncertainty Gaussian state is defined with $\psi(q-\bar{q})$ in the integral, but then next to the integral the author gives you the definition of $\psi(q)$ and $\textbf{not}$ of $\psi(q-\bar{q})$.
So you have that the the minimum-uncertainty Gaussian state, in the position representation, reads
\begin{equation}
\psi(q-\bar{q})=[2\pi(\Delta q)^2]^{-1/4} e^{-\frac{(q-\bar{q})^2}{4(\Delta q)^2}}e^{i\frac{\bar{p}q}{\hbar}}
\end{equation}

This is exactly the same state as in Cohen-Tannoudji's book. Cohen-Tannoudji defines the minimum-uncertainty Gaussian state state as $\psi(q)$ while Freire defines it as $\psi(q-\bar{q})$, simply because he wants to highlight the fact that the gaussian is "shifted" by the term $\bar{q}$ from the origin.